# Unique name for redux form

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

So I'm trying to make generalised Form component that I export:

```
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'form name', // I'd like to set this based on this.props.name
  validate           // & this.props.validate (but obviously props isn't accessible)
})(Form)
```

but obviously the export statement is outside the class component, so it doesn't have access to the name/validate props of this specific Form.

Is it possible to do? Or have I misunderstood how I should be structuring this?

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question.

Based on `reduxForm` architect, of course it tries to setup a string, for instance, unique identifier, so that if you have multiple form, the values can be arranged in the right objects.

If you want to attach another string, then you are looking at the run-time variable of a form, which is exactly a `field` :)

Give you an example, `form1.values["name"] = "Form1"`. Btw I might not give you the right syntax, since I'm not familiar with `reduxForm`, but the idea is similar.